Sidebar glitching in mobile firefox browsers
My website's sidebar is glitching on mobile firefox browsers
Here is a video I made about it. and
This link is for my site.
/* css related to sidebar */

.side-bar {
  flex: 0 0 var(--fb-sidebar-fixed);
  background-color: var(--clr-neutral-700);
  z-index: 9999;
}

.side-bar.hidden {
  margin-left: calc(-1 * var(--fb-sidebar-fixed));
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .side-bar.hidden {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  .side-bar {
    position: fixed;
    transition: transform var(--as-nav) ease;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
    width: var(--fb-sidebar-fixed);
  }
}

